# How to accept a "touch" on iOS as an "enter"

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner with Ruby, however I have a couple of friends and colleagues who understand it. I'm trying to make a simple dart randomizer that will help me with my dart practice. I had a friend who very kindly created a simple program for me that works on my PC...I downloaded Rubyist for iPhone, and while the program runs, there is no way for me to hit enter to keep the randomizer going! Since I'm such a beginner, I don't even know where to start with adding the ability to touch the screen to continue (or adding a button that allows me to hit enter).

I realize this forum is really catered for more technical-type questions, so I appreciate you reading this if you've made it this far!

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#! ruby
BOARD = ['single','double','triple'] 
RANGE = 20
puts "Welcome to Dart Target Hunter... (press return to continue to next target)\n"
while STDIN.gets do
  target = rand(RANGE + 1) 
  multiplier = (target == 0) ? rand(BOARD.size - 1) : rand(BOARD.size)  
  puts "Try to hit --> #{BOARD[multiplier]} #{(target == 0) ? "bullseye" : target}"
end
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: this sounds a little bit to me like a limitation within the iOS app and not a limitation of ruby, because ruby doesnt run on iOS and the language itself provides no support for it, your code runs perfectly fine in a computer terminal. Might be better suited to throw on Reddit, or if the iOS app has a github issues page, or a support page to report the issue there.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge in iOS programming, but my gut-feeling is that you can't use standard input in an iOS application for receiving the user input. I would first focus on a simpler program first: Write a Ruby program which reads one string from the user, and outputs the string back. The Ruby logic is trivial, but you would have to get input/output right on the iPhone. Also, tag your question with _ios_ as well, to attrackt the attention of people who know iOS-programming.

Comment: Thank you @alilland and user1934428 for your help! I will look into whether there is a GitHub issues page now that I know the issue is likely with the iOS app. Thanks again!